# Calling ACF field that is on custom taxonomy post

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I have a page, which has the same name as a term within my custom taxonomy 'classes'.

On that page I wish to echo an ACF field from the matching taxonomy.

I've managed to call the taxonomy using the page name and specifying the name of the custom taxonomy, however when I try to echo the ACF field, it doesn't return anything.

Here is the code, including a few echoes for testing.

On my page I just get 'classes35' from the name of the taxonomy and the taxonomy ID. Nothing else returns.

```
if ( have_posts() )
while ( have_posts() ): the_post();

$post_slug = ( $post->post_name );

$terms = get_terms( array(
'taxonomy' => 'classes',
'slug' => $post_slug
) );

foreach ( $terms as $term ) {

echo $term->taxonomy;
echo $term->term_taxonomy_id;

$thumbnail = get_field('field_test', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_id);

$thumbnail2 = get_field('field_test', $term->taxonomy . '_' . $term->term_taxonomy_id);

$thumbnail3 = get_field('field_test', $term);

echo $thumbnail;
echo $thumbnail2;
echo $thumbnail3;

}
```

Comment: And if you set only $term->term_id for the second argument of get_field() ?

Comment: $thumbnail3 = get_field('field_test', $term->term_id);

This doesn't output anything either unfortunately. Maybe its something to do with the scope? My php knowledge isnt great

Comment: Add comments to everywhere you have echo'ed so I can see the output value of each please :) Also are you trying to display all thumbnails of each post in that taxonomy or just 1?